# Some issues with the row layout of a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have the following very basic layout for each row of a `ListView`. The two `TextViews` should be one on top of the other or in other words in two lines or such. However, I am seeing them in the same line or not seeing them at all. Also, sometimes I see that the rows height is very big. Can anyone tell me what's the problem with my layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60px"
        android:layout_height="45px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="4px"
        android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/ahsan" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="70px"
        android:layout_y="60px"
        android:text="@+id/TextView01"
        android:textSize="18px" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="70px"
        android:layout_y="90px"
        android:text="@+id/TextView02"
        android:textSize="18px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="100px">

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/icon" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon" 
android:layout_marginLeft="4px">
</ImageView>
<TextView 
android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/label"
android:textSize="18px"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
android:layout_y="60px">
</TextView>

<TextView 
android:text="@+id/TextView02" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/label2"
android:textSize="18px"
android:layout_below="@+id/label"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon">
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add android:orientation="vertical" attribute in the LienarLayout tag

Answer (score 2):

According to the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) the default orientation of the LinearLayout is horizontal, which means, your ImageView and TextViews are in one line. So the too big height of your line is caused by the height of the ImageView.

Add  `android:orientation="vertical"` to the LinearLayout parameters.

Comment: ok, so I did what you told, now the problem is, all the text is coming directly below the image and not beside the image as i want. I changed the layout for the imageview to this :  `<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/icon" 
 android:layout_height="45px"
 android:layout_width="60px"
 android:src="@drawable/ahsan"
 android:layout_x="10px"
 android:layout_y="5px"> 
 </ImageView>`

Comment: Check @slukian's link, that is perfect for you. Just imagine what you want. First you need a LinearLayout. You divide this into 2 parts: an ImageView and a the two TextViews near the Imageview. So what do you need? You need to place the ImageView and another LinearLayout in the first LinearLayout. The orientation of this 1st LinearLayout is horizontal, so the ImageView and the 2nd LinearLayout are near each other. The last step is to put the two TextViews in the 2nd LinearLayout, which has a vertical orientation so one of them is on top of the other. Easy!

Answer (score 2):

Copy paste the follwing code in your layout..It will work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="40dip"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp" android:text="Name"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/phone" android:layout_below="@id/name"
         android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="18dp"
        android:text="Name"></TextView>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/style"
        android:textSize="18dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Style"
        android:textColor="#0E8C3A" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/style"  android:text="Style"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```